# Stokes theorem on oriented curve of form $(x+y+z)dx + x^2dy+xyzdz$

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

This is the formulation, which is not clear to me entirely.

Let $S$ be the upper unit half-sphere (this probably means the set $\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\geq 0\}$) in the right half-plane plane(I need clarification on what this means), oriented outward with the boundary $\gamma:x^2+y^2=1.$ Apply Stokes' theorem on the form    $(x+y+z)dx + x^2dy+xyz\ dz$ on the boundary $\gamma,$ of surface $S$.

I have used the Stokes theorem before but in more clear situations. Input very appreciated. Exam coming up in two days, need to get this concept down.

I am to just apply the Stokes theorem on the half-sphere, taking the boundary as just the unit circle. That simple??

Comment: I think you have the unit sphere correct, but upper probably means $z>=0$. That also fits better with its boundary $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Are you translating from a foreign language into English? Why is a "boundary" called "ending"?

Comment: I'll edit that. I am translating. :)

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: It seems that the rest of the problem is also mistranslated: I believe that $S$ is supposed to be in the right half-*space* (asuming that you draw $z$ to the right). Alternatively, if the $z$ axis points upwards, then it should be "the upper half-space". And yes, you just have to apply Stokes' theorem, transforming the integral on $S$ into an integral on the circle that is the boundary of $S$.